# Abnormal behaviour of strncpy_s function

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

Developing a program in VC++ using Win32 API;s for Windows 7 32-bit OS.
I used strncpy_s function mentioned in string.h for secure copying, but it crashes in some machines.

```
#if __STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB__
_Check_return_wat_ _CRTIMP_ALTERNATIVE errno_t __cdecl strncpy_s(_Out_z_cap_(_SizeInBytes) char * _Dst, _In_ rsize_t _SizeInBytes, _In_z_ const char * _Src, _In_ rsize_t _MaxCount);
#endif
```

Here is the stacktrace

```
>   msvcr100.dll!malloc(unsigned int size)  Line 89 + 0x3b bytes    C
    mfc100u.dll!operator new(unsigned int nSize)  Line 323 + 0x5 bytes  C++
    MyTest.exe!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::_Copy(unsigned int _Newsize, unsigned int _Oldlen)  Line 1933 + 0x16 bytes C++
    MyTest.exe!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::assign(const char * _Ptr, unsigned int _Count)  Line 920 + 0x26 bytes  C++
    MyTest.exe!std::basic_stringbuf<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::str()  Line 97 + 0x2a bytes C++
    MyTest.exe!std::basic_ostringstream<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::str()  Line 593 + 0x12 bytes    C++
    MyTest.exe!Trace<TraceToFile>::~Trace<TraceToFile>()  Line 174 + 0xa bytes  C++
    MyTest.exe!CCommonUtilities::sendDataToClient(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > strJson, int nCommandID, std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > strFuncName, int nLineNumber, int nClientKey)  Line 320    C++
    MyTest.exe!CConnectionManager::AddConnectionThread(void * p_Param)  Line 270 + 0x74 bytes   C++
```

**Based on this, can someone point if this is issue with strncpy_s or programming error ?**

I never get issue if I try to debug the code. It always come when we execute this binary.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: The information provided isn't enough to diagnose the problem but I'd be extremely surprised if there was a bug in `strncpy_s`.  You should be safe to proceed on the assumption that there is a bug in your code.  If running a debug build masks the bug, try adding logging statements to a release build.

Comment: Why are you using `strncpy_s` in C++ code?

Comment: A guess in the dark, something is uninitialized in your code (often explains difference in debug/release) causing malloc to get a huge number and explode. Without seeing your code, who can tell.

Comment: There are no bugs in strncpy_s() I'm aware of. It's also extremely unlikely that you've found one. It's a safe bet to say that it's a programming error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash isn't in `strncpy_s` - it doesn't appear on the stack trace.

The crash is in corrupt memory; in your `Trace<>` destructor, you are creating a `std::basic_string<>` object which tries to allocated memory and finds the heap is corrupt.

Look at the code in `~Trace<>` or `CCommonUtilities::sendDataToClient()` as a starting point to finding the corruption.

Why do you think it's `strncpy_n()` ?

Answer (score 0):

The "safety" of `strncpy_s` comes not so much from the implementation of the function as from the caller providing valid inputs, and the function checking that you don't go over the limits.

In other words, if you lie to `strncpy_s` abotue the size of the destination (second parameter), or you pass it an invalid address as the source or destination, then it will go wrong in some way.